# remove whitespace long at first json data in pre tag html

Tags: java, html, css, json

I use framework struts and i want display json string from variable java

```
String test = "{\n  \"fileName\": \"\",\n  \"fileUrl\": \"\",\n  \"accountId\": ,\n  \"totalRow\": \n}";
```

Display on browser :
[image: whitespace pre tag]

And view source chrome browser :
[image: sorce whitespace pre tag]

How can i remove whitespace at first and last pre tag to display pretty json data

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem. Because distance of pre tag and s:property tag of struts framework :

Error :
[image]

Solve : move s:property to near pre tag

```
<pre><s:property value="test" /></pre>
```

It's display pretty json data like : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a proper answer but I can give you a hint that You can use **Regular Expressions** for solving your problem. I'll surely help you.

Comment: I don't know how to use regex in java, you can search it on your own. Anyways you have solved your problem so give your time to regex when have free time.